# Presto SQL - product combination matrix to find substitutes

Tags: sql, presto

I have this **input** (product list table and its buyers)

```
product_id  customer_id 
p1         c1                   
p2         c1
p2         c2                  
p3         c1                   
p3         c2                    
p4         c2
```

and need to get this dynamic matrix **output** in SQL, Presto.

```
      p1   p2   p3   p4
p1          2    1    0         
p2               2    1                                                
p3                    1
p4
```

any thoughts are very appreciated

Comment: Can we get more information like what query did you try.?

Comment: SQL is statically typed language, so set of output columns needs to be known before running the query. See also https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1206.